# Returns per day and per company calculation in dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, for-loop, group-by, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe looking like this:

```
Index       date        company_tic      price
0        2020-01-01         xyz          20.89
1        2021-02-24         zyx          18.15
2        2020-01-02         xyz          20.14
3        2021-03-05         abc          28.19
4        2021-02-28         zyx          14.99
5        2021-03-06         abc          15.78
...      ...                ...          ...
159236 x 3
```

For each company (company_tic), I want to calculate the daily returns, with the following formula: ((price today - price 1 day prior) / price 1 day prior).

I would like the returns to appear in a new column in the existing dataframe. If data is not available on the day prior, show np.nan.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`groupby.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) with a DatetimeIndex to access the prior day's price. Then perform the computation:

```
# ensure datetime
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

prev = (df[['date', 'company_tic']]
        .merge(
 df.set_index('date')
   .groupby('company_tic')
   ['price']
   .shift(1, 'D').reset_index(),
    how='left'
 )['price']
)

df['return'] = df['price'].sub(prev).div(prev)
```

Output:

```
        date company_tic  price    return
0 2020-01-01         xyz  20.89       NaN
1 2021-02-24         zyx  18.15       NaN
2 2020-01-02         xyz  20.14 -0.035902
3 2021-03-05         abc  28.19       NaN
4 2021-02-28         zyx  14.99       NaN
5 2021-03-06         abc  15.78 -0.440227
```

Comment: This seems to only work for a small amount of data, I applied this code to a bigger dataframe and some returns are not calculated properly, it sometimes gives returns of like 48.5005 or 36.0453, for price variations of like 1-2%, which does not make sense. How would you solve this? Thank you.

Comment: @Marie-Pier please provide a counter example for which my code doesn't work

Comment: For some lines, the calculation somehow did not work, For a 1 day difference, I have prices of 10.5 and 10.07, and the return shows 6.04698. There are a few lines that the calculation does something like that and the return is a number above 4.00, which does not apply in my case. How may I solve this? Thank you very much your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    [
        {'date': '2020-01-01', 'company_tic': 'xyz', 'price': 20.89},
        {'date': '2021-02-24', 'company_tic': 'zyx', 'price': 18.15},
        {'date': '2020-01-02', 'company_tic': 'xyz', 'price': 20.14},
        {'date': '2021-03-05', 'company_tic': 'abc', 'price': 28.19},
        {'date': '2021-02-28', 'company_tic': 'zyx', 'price': 14.99},
        {'date': '2021-03-06', 'company_tic': 'abc', 'price': 15.78}
    ]
)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    prior_date = row.date - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    price_prior = df[(df.date==prior_date) & (df.company_tic == row.company_tic)].price
    price_prior = float(price_prior) if not price_prior.empty else np.nan
    df.loc[i, 'daily_return'] = (row.price - price_prior) / price_prior

print(df)
```

```
         date company_tic  price  daily_return
0  2020-01-01         xyz  20.89           NaN
1  2021-02-24         zyx  18.15           NaN
2  2020-01-02         xyz  20.14     -0.035902
3  2021-03-05         abc  28.19           NaN
4  2021-02-28         zyx  14.99           NaN
5  2021-03-06         abc  15.78     -0.440227
```

Comment: What if there are way more rows in the dataframe containing more daily prices and companies (sorry I just adjusted the question), would there be a faster way to proceed, maybe without a manually constructed dictionary? Thank you!

Comment: Your code doesn't work, can we find an alternative? Thank you very much for your help.